# Loading local html into webengine while using svn

Tags: java, svn, javafx, javafx-2

Currently I have my project uploaded onto my svn.  I also have other users that access this svn and download the project.  The problem I have currently is that I have to provide an absolute path to my `WebEngine.load();` The html that I load is in my eclipse project under a certain package.  I am trying to find a solution where I don't have to provide an absolute path but a relative path to the html file.

My call to load the html via relative path:

```
engine.load("file:///com.interpro.emmeclipse/src/com/interpro/emmeclipse/html/PageCreator.html");
```

relative path:

```
/com.interpro.emmeclipse/src/com/interpro/emmeclipse/html/PageCreator.html
```

Absolute path:

```
C:\Users\dparker.INTERPRO\Desktop\emmeclipse\src\com\interpro\emmeclipse\html\PageCreator.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by starting the file path from the source folder.

```
 engine.load(getClass().getResource("/src/com/interpro/emmeclipse/html/PageCreator.html").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
engine.load(getClass()
    .getResource("/com/interpro/emmeclipse/html/PageCreator.html")
    .toExternalForm());
```

It *should* run for a JAR-packaged application too, but test it anyway...